# How to expand ... in powershell when you want to display multiple columns?

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I am trying to display `Name` and `FullName` Property of the directory object in the below powershell script

`gci C:\abc\*\* |  where {$_.PsIsContainer} |select Name, FullName |sort Name -u`.

But the `FullName` property displays `...` after certain characters in the Path of the directory.

Any one knows how do I display all the values for Name & FullName property?

`Select-Object -ExpandProperty` only works when you need to display only one field i guess.

Any help?

Answer (score 7):

Use the `Format-Table` cmdlet, aka `ft` like so,

```
gci C:\abc** | where {$_.PsIsContainer} |select Name, FullName |sort Name -u | ft -wrap
```

This will cause the output to wrap on multiple rows in case it doesn't fit on the screen.

Answer (score 3):

You can also try with the -autosize option in Format-Table

```
gci C:\abc** | where {$_.PsIsContainer} |select Name, FullName |sort Name -u | ft -autosize
```

Additionally, you can always make your Powershell console bigger if still things does not fit that way. Here's how

```
$host.UI.RawUI.BufferSize = New-Object System.Management.Automation.Host.Size(8192,500)
```

That should give you a nice and long horizontal scrollbar to view the full values in the columns